# error whilst trying to create digital ocean droplet via terraform

Tags: linux, server, terraform, digital-ocean

Hi So I am trying to run my terraform script to get my server up but I get this very strange issue. Google results have come up with nothing.

```
digitalocean_droplet.ubuntubox: Creating...

Error: Error creating droplet: Post "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets":      dial tcp: lookup api.digitalocean.com on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:52870->[::1]:53:     read: connection refused

on droplet_backup.tf line 2, in resource "digitalocean_droplet" "ubuntubox":
2: resource "digitalocean_droplet" "ubuntubox" {
```

this is my droplet_backup.tf file with the droplet block

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "ubuntubox" {
image  = "ubuntu-20-04-x64"
name   = "Valheim_Server"
region = "LON1"
#size   = "s-4vcpu-8gb"
size   = "s-1vcpu-1gb"
private_networking = "true"
ssh_keys = [var.ssh_fingerprint]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These errors suggest that your host is unable to lookup DigitalOcean's API endpoint (`api.digitalocean.com`).

`[::1]:53: read udp [::1]:52870->[::1]:53` port `:53` is DNS and that your error includes these suggests that this is where the issue is arising.

Can you `dig api.digitalocean.com A` or `nslookup api.digitalocean.com` or perhaps (although this is ICMP not TCP) `ping api.digitalocean.com`?

If I `dig` the host:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
api.digitalocean.com.   169 IN  A   104.16.182.15
api.digitalocean.com.   169 IN  A   104.16.181.15
```

And, using a DNS lookup service (e.g. Google's [link](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/)), these values are corroborated.

Comment: I did the nslookup command and this is what I got

nslookup api.digitalocean.com   
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached.

Seems it is blocking the connection some how

Comment: The DNS resolution for your machine has *challenges*. I'd focus your energies there until you can get that API endpoint to resolve correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Symlinked /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf/ to /etc/resolv.conf fixed the issue.